# Erro em soma de números tipo Double - VBA/VB

Tags: vba, visual-basic-6, double

veja a situação:

Tenho uma rotina que faz uma soma de Preço * Qtd e armazena em uma variável para mostrar o total.

A soma é composta de 226 itens. A partir do 215 o resultado parcial da soma seria 4750,10 porém é mostrado 4750,099999999999999, sendo que todos os números multiplicados são inteiros e decimais com 2 casas.

Fiz a mesma simulação no Excel, em VBA, e ocorre o mesmo problema.

A única solução que encontrei foi alterar o tipo da variável que armazena o total para SINGLE ao invés de DOUBLE. Com isso o erro não aparece.

Gostaria de saber se alguém já passou por isso e se há alguma limitação que provoca esse tipo de situação.

**Rotina em VBA:**

***Sub Test()***

```
Dim Line As Integer, Total As Double
Dim Qty As Double
Dim Price As Double

Line = 2
Do While Planilha1.Cells(Line, 1) <> ""
    Price = Planilha1.Cells(Line, 2)
    Qty = Planilha1.Cells(Line, 3)
    Total = Total + (Price * Qty)
    'Aqui, na linha 215, o resultado da soma mostra 4750.09999999 quando de fato é  4750.10
    If Line = 215 Then MsgBox Total
    Line = Line + 1
Loop
MsgBox Total
```

End Sub

Se trocar a declaração da variável **Total** para o tipo ***Single***, o problema não acontece.

Neste link está a planilha, com a devida macro que mostra o problema:

http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=07636099064547863256

Agradeço qualquer ajuda.

Comment: "[...] o resultado parcial da soma seria 4750,10". Se o resultado da soma tem casas decimais, os números utilizados não são inteiros. Além disso, o fato dos números com decimais só terem duas casas não impede resultados com mais casas. Faça na sua calculadora a conta `1285 * 0,33 * 0,77` (aqui na minha resultou em `326,5185`). Ou seja, o resultado pode estar *essencialmente certo*, só que com uma precisão alta demais para o que vc deseja. Você tentou simplesmente arredondar para duas casas decimais?

Comment: Função `round` no Excel: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/ROUND-function-C018C5D8-40FB-4053-90B1-B3E7F61A213C

Comment: Olá Luiz, obrigado pela ajuda.

No caso, as contas são sempre de um numero decimal com duas casas por outro valor inteiro (preço * quantidade).

Imagino mesmo pelo fato de estar usando Double está mostrando uma precisão desnecessária, porém não consegui visualizar onde que essa precisão está resultando neste valor, uma vez que, no exemplo, os valores não permitiriam tal resultado com 3 ou mais casas decimais.

Caso utilize a função Format no VBA o problema deixa de existir, assim como se declarar a variavel que armazena o total para do tipo Single.